Cannot access getter of base class
I have a base class like this
export class ShortNameFullNameBaseDto extends DtoBase<number> {
  public shortName: string = '';
  public fullName: string = '';

  public get uniqueName(): string {
    return `${this.shortName} - ${this.fullName}`;
  }
}

And an inherited class like this
export class FundDto extends ShortNameFullNameBaseDto {
  public sebiRegistrationNumber: string = '';
  public investmentManagerName: string = '';
  public sponsorName: string = '';
  public merchantBankerName: string = '';
  public legalAdvisorName: string = '';
  public fundHouseId: number = null;
  public fundHouse: FundHouseDto = null;
}

I load FundDto from web api, after that I am expecting that when I will call FundDto.uniqueName property I should get it but I am always getting this property undefined.
This is how I am loading array of FundDto objects
this.commonService.getAllFunds(e.value).then(response => {
  if (response.isSuccess) {
    this.funds = response.data;
  }
});

What am I doing wrongly?
It is the loading of object from web api response creating the problem?
Update
I just tried this code and it works perfectly. So looks like it is because I am copying the data to FundDto object which I receive from web api response and the response does not have uniqueName property.
const fund = new FundDto();
fund.shortName = 'short name';
fund.fullName = 'full name';

console.log(fund.uniqueName); // here it works

How to make it work in this case then?

What type is 'response ' from getAllFunds? can u cast it to FundDto?

How to make it work in this case then? - What's still unclear to you? Your API response is a plain Javascript object, so you'll need to map the response to an instance of FundDto. Something like this.funds = response.data.map(item => new FundDto(item)) should work, granted you add a constructor that accepts the API object.

Generally when you call to an API you received a simple json Object, not a class. To assing the properties to a class use Object.assign
this.commonService.getAllFunds(e.value).then(response => {
  if (response.isSuccess) {
    this.funds = Object.assign(new FundDto(), response.data);;
  }
});

NOTE: You can, instead of use the Obsect.assign in the "then" use in the service

You can, instead of use the Obsect.assign in the "then" use in the service What do you mean with this?

@Verity, I don't know about your service. You can make that the service return a object of the class FundDto or a simple json object as looks like your service return.
